# Select rows and those with timestamps close to it

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series

I have a table containing timeseries data and want to select a number of rows based on some "first" criteria as well as those with timestamps close to those select based on the first criteria.

Example table:

| ts | val |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 09:55:00 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 09:55:57 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:10 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:20 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:25 | 2 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:30 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:57 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:15 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:35 | 5 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:55 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:21:01 | 1 |
| 2022-11-01 10:21:30 | 1 |

From this table, I want to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE val > 1` plus any rows with `ts` close to those rows, for example a) within +/- 30 second time difference or b) within the same "absolute" minute (e.g. from second 00 of the minute of the timestamp until second 59.

So as a result of option a), I would like to get:

| ts | val | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:00 | 1 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:10 | 1 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:20 | 1 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:25 | 2 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:30 | 1 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:15 | 1 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:35 | 5 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:55 | 1 | Data within 30 s of 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |

or in case of option b),
So as a result of option a), I would like to get:

| ts | val | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:00 | 1 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:10 | 1 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:20 | 1 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:25 | 2 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:00:25 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:30 | 1 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:57 | 1 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:15 | 1 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:35 | 5 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:55 | 1 | Same minute as 2022-11-01 10:20:35 |

I tried to get option a) working using a subquery and `DATEDIFF`, but it seems this won't work because it's not possible to use `DATEDIFF` and such functions on subqueries. This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(second, t.ts,  (SELECT ts FROM table WHERE val > 1))) <= 30
```

What's the best way to get this working only using SQL and for large tables?

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not possible to use DATEDIFF* - please include your current query attempt and also actual desired results for the sample data.

Comment: @Stu I added my desired results & also my (obviously bad) attempt.

Comment: Your example results don't match your explanation, for example `09:55:57` is not within 30 seconds of `10:00:25`, it's 268 seconds different. Why is this included?

Comment: @Stu this was a mistake - fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your first requirement (a question really should focus on a single problem only), one way you can accomplish this is by using an *exists* semi-join, comparing each `ts` date with qualifying min and max dates derived in the *exists* criteria.

Your second (or any other) criteria can work a very similar way.

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (
  select * from t t2
    cross apply (values(
      case when val > 1 then DateAdd(second, -30, ts) end,
      case when val > 1 then DateAdd(second, 30, ts) end)
    )r(rmin,rmin)
  where t.ts >= rmin and t.ts <= rmin
) order by ts;
```

See demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LmfoszU9)

Comment: Thanks. This gives the desired result. On a larger table (6 million rows, index on ts) it takes forever to run though... not sure if there's a way to speed this up using another index or another query?

Comment: Yes possibly, although tuning a query is really a different question which requires seeing the full query, the table schema and indexes and the actual execution plan; For an index to be useful doesn't just require it exists, the cardinality must warrant it, it must be selective and also covering - eg don't actually use `select *`. Other options exist such as indexed computed columns.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is still somewhat unclear for me, but here is an example of using `DATEDIFF` to calculate the minute difference between timestamps (see this identical [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fVTVZlCn)):

Create the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events (
  event_ts DATETIME,
  event_value INTEGER
);
```

Populate with data (I've added a row to better illustrate the query):

```sql
INSERT INTO events VALUES
  ('2022-11-01 10:00:00', 1),
  ('2022-11-01 10:00:10', 1),
  ('2022-11-01 10:00:20', 1),
  ('2022-11-01 10:00:25', 2),
  ('2022-11-01 10:00:30', 1),
  ('2022-11-01 10:00:55', 1),
  ('2022-11-01 10:20:15', 1),
  ('2022-11-01 10:20:35', 5),
  ('2022-11-01 10:20:55', 1),
  ('2022-11-01 10:30:55', 6)
```

Query:

```sql
WITH events_filtered AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM events
  WHERE event_value > 1
)

SELECT
  *,
  DATEDIFF(mi, e1.event_ts, e2.event_ts) AS event_minute_difference
FROM events_filtered AS e1
INNER JOIN events_filtered AS e2
ON e1.event_ts < e2.event_ts
```

I've split the two conditions into a CTE and a final query for the sake of clarity (but you could and probably should contain this in the same query). The result is:

| event_ts | event_value | event_ts | event_value | event_minute_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:25.000 | 2 | 2022-11-01 10:20:35.000 | 5 | 20 |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:25.000 | 2 | 2022-11-01 10:30:55.000 | 6 | 30 |
| 2022-11-01 10:20:35.000 | 5 | 2022-11-01 10:30:55.000 | 6 | 10 |

I cannot comment of performance (and opportunities for improving performance) without really knowing more about the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't explain my desired result well enough, as this is not it... I added the exact desired output and my attempt to the question.